# Does ORDER BY sort first and then Offsets and Fetches or does it perform the sort only on the fetched columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, ssms

```
ORDER BY (CASE @Lang WHEN 'fr' THEN [SUBS_NAME_F] ELSE [SUBS_NAME_E] END)
OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * @ItemsPerPage ROWS
FETCH NEXT @ItemsPerPage ROW ONLY
```

This is a part of the stored procedure that I believe is creating my problem.

The issue is when I run the query on my site I get a different order of results based on the `@ItemsPerPage` value, for example a value of 50 and a value of 500 will produce different results when looking at the first few rows pulled.

I think this happens because I'm pulling 50 (or `@ItemsPerPage` amount) rows I need, then they get sorted by `ORDER BY`, which results in a different sort result. Is my assumption correct or is my error somewhere else? And if this is correct then is there any way to fix this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` is executed first.  In general, all the data is sorted, although this might be made more efficient by using an index.

`FETCH` then fetches the rows after the `OFFSET` -- which is zero-based rather than one-based.  So, the first row has an `OFFSET` of 0, so the 50th row has an offset of 49.

If the `ORDER BY` has ties in the key values, then these can appear in an arbitrary order.  SQL has no built in ordering of either result sets or tables.  So ties can appear in any order.  The solution is to include a unique value -- such as the primary key -- as the final key.

Comment: Interesting, so what could affect the query results simply based off the @ItemsPerPage value? Because if it sorts first and then returns the number of rows specified shouldn't the top of my results be the same regardless?